# How to use youtube api in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

Type : "channel"

For Video only specify > Type : "video"

For Playlist only specify > Type : "playlist"

maxResults(int) can be 1 - 50'

```
int max = 25;

String type = "channel";

YoutubeAPI ytApi = new YoutubeAPI(key,
                                  maxResults: max,
                                  Type: type);
```

this code to get  json data to store in ytResult  :

```
[
    {
        "kind": "video",
        "id": "9vzd289Eedk",
        "channelTitle": "Java",
        "title": "WEBINAR - Programmatic Trading in Indian Markets using Python with Kite Connect API",
         "description": "For traders today, Python is the most preferred programming language for trading, as it provides great flexibility in terms of building and executing strategies.",
        "publishedAt":"2016-10-18T14:41:14.000Z",
        "channelId": "UC8kXgHG13XdgsigIPRmrIyA",
        "thumbnails": {
             "default": {
              "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/9vzd289Eedk/default.jpg",
              "width": 120,
              "height": 90
             },
             "medium": {
              "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/9vzd289Eedk/mqdefault.jpg",
              "width": 320,
              "height": 180
             },
             "high": {
              "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/9vzd289Eedk/hqdefault.jpg",
              "width": 480,
              "height": 360
             }
        },
        "channelurl":"https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC8kXgHG13XdgsigIPRmrIyA",
        "url":"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9vzd289Eedk"
    },
    {
      "kind": "video"
       // Here will you next result
    },
    {
       // Here will you next result
    },
    {
       // Here will you next result
        "url":"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9vzd289Eedk"
    }
 ]
```

it's all of my code but didn't get any response

Comment: Please edit your question to make it clearer. It seems you've copied lots of content from plugins home page and put it in here. You need to put your own code that doesn't work so we can help.

Comment: same issue here. did you get any solution ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is my flutter code to list videos by keyword

```
import 'package:cached_network_image/cached_network_image.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:youtube_api/youtube_api.dart';
import 'package:timeago/timeago.dart' as timeago;
import '../../generated/l10n.dart';
import './video.dart';



class VideosPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _VideosPageState createState() => _VideosPageState();
}

class _VideosPageState extends State<VideosPage>
    with AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin<VideosPage> {
  static String key = "AIzaSy...__xxxxxxxx_**********";
  bool recordsLoaded = false;
  static int maxResults = 25;

//  static String videosType = "channel";
  static String videosType = "videos";
// static String videosType = "playlist";

  YoutubeAPI ytApi = new YoutubeAPI(
    key,
    maxResults: maxResults,
    type: videosType,
  );
  List<YT_API> ytResult = [];

  callAPI() async {
   // print('UI callled');
//    CircularProgressIndicator();
    String query = "FLUTTER"; 
    ytResult = await ytApi.search(query);
    setState(() {
//      print('UI Updated 2');
      recordsLoaded = true;
    });
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
//    _loadList();
//    super.initState();
    super.initState();
    callAPI();
//    print('hello');
    recordsLoaded = false;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    super.build(context);
//    var locale = Localizations.localeOf(context).languageCode;
    timeago.setLocaleMessages('fr', timeago.FrMessages());
    timeago.setLocaleMessages('en', timeago.EnMessages());

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(S.of(context).titleVideos),
        elevation: 0,
      ),
      body: Container(
          child: recordsLoaded
              ? ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: ytResult.length,
                  itemBuilder: (_, int index) => listItem(index))
              : Center(
                  child: Container(
                    child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                  ),
                )),
    );
  }

  Widget listItem(index) {
    var publishedAt =
        timeago.format(DateTime.parse(ytResult[index].publishedAt));
    return new Card(
      child: new Container(
        margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 7.0),
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(6.0),
        child: new Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            new InkWell(
              child: new CachedNetworkImage(
                imageUrl: ytResult[index].thumbnail['default']['url'],
                width: 90,
                height: 90,
              ),
              onTap: () {
                print(ytResult[index].url);
                Navigator.push(
                  context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(
                    builder: (context) => YouTubeVideoPlayer(
                        title: ytResult[index].title, url: ytResult[index].id),
                  ),
                );
              },
            ),
            new Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 10.0)),
            new Expanded(
                child: new Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: <Widget>[
                  new InkWell(
                    child: new Text(
                      ytResult[index].title,
                      softWrap: true,
                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16.0),
                    ),
                    onTap: () {
                      Navigator.push(
                        context,
                        MaterialPageRoute(
                          builder: (context) => YouTubeVideoPlayer(
                              title: ytResult[index].title,
                              url: ytResult[index].id),
                        ),
                      );
                    },
                  ),
                  new Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 1.5)),
                  new Text(
                    ytResult[index].channelTitle,
                    softWrap: true,
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 14.0, color: Colors.grey[600]),
                  ),
                  new Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 3.0)),
                  new Text(
                    publishedAt,
                    softWrap: true,
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12.0, color: Colors.grey),
                  ),
                ]))
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

}
```